# Reliable method to get the command for last pressed key?

Tags: key-bindings

I'm writing some code where I have to identify the command for the last key pressed. Sometimes I need to look up a combination of this key with another one. I use the `key-binding` function for that. It works most of the time but not for all keys. For example it does not work for the backspace key:

```
(progn
  (read-key)
  (key-binding (vector last-input-event))) ;; > nil for backspace
```

I can work around this by checking for backspace manually but I wonder if there is a more reliable way that works for all/most situations?

I use `last-input-event` because it is after exiting a keymap through the default binding `[t]`.

**Edit:**

Based on the accepted answer I'm using something like the following which seems to work very well:

```
(progn
  (read-key)
  (key-binding (kbd (edmacro-format-keys (vector last-input-event)))))
```

Comment: Maybe you can find the info you need in the `last-command` variable: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/last_002dcommand-_0026-this_002dcommand.html

Comment: @Tyler Thanks, unfortunately that does not work for my case, because the commands I search for were not invoked before.

Comment: Why not just `(key-binding (vector (read-char)))` ? It looks like `(vector last-input-event)` doesn't always hold a valid key representation, at least for some function keys such as backspace, tab and return

Comment: @xuchunyang The code in my question is a contrived example I have to use last-input-event in my case because there is no manual invoked query for the key. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: You could look at `(recent-keys t)` and the definition of `view-lossage`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can repurpose part of the kbd-macro infrastructure for this, specifically `edmacro-format-keys`. It already handles [*a lot* of edge cases](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/1ee91bf89176251f6e399c8436dca0248cdd6f6b/lisp/edmacro.el#L423) for you. For example:

```
(edmacro-format-keys (kbd "DEL") t) 
=> "DEL         ;; backward-delete-char-untabify"
```

and

```
(edmacro-format-keys (kbd "C-x C-s") t)
=> "C-x C-s         ;; save-buffer"
```

Answer (score 0):

backspace and a lot of other keys are [function keys](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Keys.html#Function-Keys) for which, the event is a symbol so there is nothing in the keymaps for it.

```
(progn
  (read-key)
  (cond
    ((symbolp last-input-event) last-input-event)
    (t (key-binding (vector last-input-event)))))
```

The above still doesn't get you the function for the symbol of the function key.

```
(let (( key (read-key-sequence "hit a key:")) 
     (message "key %s was fun %s " key ( key-binding key t)))
```

But that uses read-key-sequence and it seems like you want to use last-input-event. Maybe take a look at the definition of describe-key in help.el