# Zoom with mouse-button + scroll wheel?

Tags: key-bindings, fonts, mouse, scaling, zooming

I'd like to enable changing the font size by holding down the right mouse button and using the scroll-wheel. Emacs does however treat mouse buttons as keys, so this obviously cannot be achieved directly by a straight-forward `(define-key ... (kbd ...) ...)` binding.

Since I also don't want to disable the standard actions performed by "click and release" of the right mouse button, I can't just bind something to `<up/down-mouse-3>`. Instead, I'd like to bind a command to the scroll events `<mouse-4>` and `<mouse-5>`, that detects, whether the right mouse button is being held.

Is this possible?

Related questions point to the variable `track-mouse`, but it doesn't seem, like that method can distinguish different mouse buttons.

Comment: You might be able to use something like the answers to [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22503/reliable-method-to-get-the-command-for-last-pressed-key) to detect if the last pressed key was `<down-mouse>`, then set a variable that you can check. Something based on [`key-chord.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/key-chord.el) might also be useful, but that would probably require more work to figure out. An easier solution, might be to add something to the right-click context menu (like a minor mode that binds scrolling to resize).

Answer (score 1):

Library [**`zoom-frm.el`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/zoom-frm.el) lets you do either of these things using the mouse wheel:

- Zoom the buffer text size, for all windows showing a given buffer. This is called *text-scaling*.
- Zoom the frame text size, for a given frame or for all frames.

It, in turn, requires these libraries:

- [`frame-cmds.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/frame-cmds.el)
- [`frame-fns.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/frame-fns.el)

See also [Changing Font Size](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SetFonts#ChangingFontSize).

These are bindings recommended in **`zoom-frm.el`** for the mouse wheel:

```lisp
(global-set-key (vector (list 'control mouse-wheel-down-event))
                'zoom-in)
(global-set-key (vector (list 'control 'meta mouse-wheel-down-event))
                'zoom-all-frames-in)
(global-set-key (vector (list 'control  mouse-wheel-up-event))
                'zoom-out)
(global-set-key (vector (list 'control 'meta mouse-wheel-up-event))
                'zoom-all-frames-out)
```

Perhaps you can provide similar bindings for simultaneous use of the wheel and holding `mouse-3` (right button) pressed. I don't know, and I'm not really motivated to find out. Perhaps someone else here will help with that.

---

For buffer (not frame) zooming, you might also want to use library [**`face-remap+.el`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/face-remap%2b.el). It lets buffer resizing also zoom the window size accordingly (horizontally, vertically, or both). That way, you can take advantage of the space freed up by resizing (text-scaling) to a smaller font.

Comment: Binding the mouse-wheel is really white easy; I have my own setup for that. The problem is mostly avoiding the use of they keyboard while scrolling through other peoples source code.

Answer (score 1):

mapping behavior similar to browser might be helpful,

- zoom in  : `Ctrl + mouse-scroll-up` and `Ctrl + Shift + =`
- zoom out : `Ctrl + mouse-scroll-down` and `Ctrl + -`
- zoom 1x  : `Ctrl + 0`

these config are for the single buffer

```lisp
(global-set-key [C-mouse-4] 'text-scale-increase)
(global-set-key [(control ?+)] 'text-scale-increase)
(global-set-key [C-mouse-5] 'text-scale-decrease)
(global-set-key [(control ?-)] 'text-scale-decrease)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-0") '(lambda () (interactive)
                               (text-scale-adjust
                                (- text-scale-mode-amount))
                               (text-scale-mode -1)))
```